# Firebase database structure for car class

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im new to Firebase, at the moment Im doing toy application and can`t find out what is the right structure to use, and how then correctly read it using addChildEventListener. It seems a bit complicated after SQL.

The idea is, there is Car class and a car has a manufacturer, model and production date.
in SQL it would be one simple table but no idea what is the best way to do it in NoSQL Firebase database. Any suggestions? thank you in advance

Comment: There is no single "best" solution for modeling data in a NoSQL database. It always depends on the use-cases of your app. Since those often evolve over time, so will your data model. For a good introduction read [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and watch [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).

Comment: Thank you @FrankvanPuffelen Already found out a solution on your Udacity course "Firebase in a Weekend". Really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it something like this

```
cars : {

    "$SOME_UNIQE_KEY":{
        manufacturer : 'SOME_VALUE' ,
        model : 'SOME_VALUE',
        productionDate : 'SOME_DATE_OR_TIMESTAMP'
    }

}
```

checkout the documentation [read and write data on android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Do you have any suggestions how to read it to array in Android?

Comment: checkout the documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Answer (score 1):

i propose this, put attention in the "10001A" is the id from th object, must be unique and is the way to search inside de db:

```
{
"cars":{
      //first car
      "10001A":{
       "model":" "
       "production":""
        ....
        }
       //second car
       "10001B":{
       "model":" "
       "production":""
        ....
        }
      }
}
```